# prevent github pipeline from being affected

Tags: ios, git, github, triggers, fastlane

I have a fastlane file in my ios project. When I increase the version number of the project and submit the code to github, the pipeline is constantly triggered. To solve this problem, I want to print the version number in another file and ignore that file. will this solve my problem? is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your pipeline is triggered via GitHub Actions.

Look on `.github/workflows/` you should have something like

```yaml
on:
  push:
```

You can exclude when to launch the pipeline and define when trigger it.

For example don't run for commit on `main` and launch it on tag starting with `v`:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:    
      - main
    tags:        
      - v*
```